# HttpWebRequest with https in C#

Tags: c#, .net, https, httpwebrequest

This piece of code doesn't work; it's logging in into website which is using https protocol. How to solve this problem? The code stops at `GetRequestStream()` anytime anywhere saying that protocol violation exception is unhandled..

```
string username = "user";
string password = "pass";
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://moje.azet.sk/prihlasenie.phtml?KDE=www.azet.sk%2Findex.phtml%3F");
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705)";

Console.WriteLine(request.GetRequestStream());

using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream(), Encoding.ASCII))
{
    writer.Write("nick=" + username + "&password=" + password);
}

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
//Retrieve your cookie that id's your session
//response.Cookies

using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
    Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
}
```

Comment: I don't have edit priviledges, but you need to obfuscate the username and password variables in your code example.  I just tried logging into the site and they got me in.

Comment: Replaced them with "user" and "pass"

Comment: You should also change your password on the site since the credentials are still in the edit history of this question.

Comment: Thx ppl, but the account was for test purposes - > I didn't really care if anyone sees it ;-)

Comment: @Birgit_B: There is [markdown for that](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code), just two backticks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set request method to post, before calling GetRequestStream

like

```
request.Method = "POST";

using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream(), Encoding.ASCII))
{
    writer.Write("nick=" + username + "&password=" + password);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that the issue you are experiencing is due to the fact (like others have advised) that you are doing a GET request instead of a POST request.  Additionally, I noticed that the actual name for the password field on that page is "heslo" and not "password".  This typo won't cause the web server to not return a response, but it will cause other issues since the server is looking for that specific variable name to be posted with the password value.

Comment: Thx, I got one more issue, not sure if i should make another question.. How do I continue to "get data from different pages from same server using same "loggged cookie and data"??

Comment: @Skuta: See HttpWebRequest.CookieContainer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.cookiecontainer.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to figure out the total length of what you're posting, beforehand, and set that as the ContentLength of the request. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse.aspx):

> A ProtocolViolationException is thrown in several cases when the properties set on the 
>   HttpWebRequest class are conflicting. This exception occurs if an application sets the 
>   ContentLength property and the SendChunked property to true, and then sends an HTTP GET 
>   request. This exception occurs if an application tries to send chunked to a server that 
>   only supports HTTP 1.0 protocol, where this is not supported. **This exception occurs if an 
>   application tries to send data without setting the ContentLength property** or the 
>   SendChunked is false when buffering is disabled and on a keepalive connection (the 
>   KeepAlive property is true).

Comment: should I just do the "strlen" check?

Comment: @skuta - Here is a sample from msdn at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.contentlength.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here is what works for me:

```
    var request = WebRequest.Create(_url);
    request.PreAuthenticate = true;
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(_userName, _password);
```