# Communicating via https within a c# web service

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, https

I've got a client who requires a secure transaction made over HTTPS. They do not provide any web services to consume, so instead they have a simple post over HTTPS with SSL. I have two applications that need to utilize this service, one is a website, one is an iOS app, so I figured to save some time and effort, I would write a proxy web service that both of these applications would use to pass data back and forth between the client's system.

So I have the web service sitting on a server, with an exposed web method which is being consumed by the application. The variables are in the method, can someone please help me with sending that data via https POST to the required URL? I've never done anything like this before and I'm a bit lost. The web service is programmed in C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using .NET 4.5, you can use the System.Net.Http.HttpClient

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx

or, System.Net.HttpWebRequest if you are using older version of the framework.

Here's an example

[HttpWebRequest with https in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542024/httpwebrequest-with-https-in-c-sharp)